# Horizontal Menu <ul> <li> clicking area to activate the link too small

Tags: css

The menu itself:

```
<ul id="menu">
        <li class=""><a href="home.asp">Home</a> </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS that is attached to the menu:

```
#menu li {
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 7px 25px;
    z-index: 100;
}
newMenu.css (line 36)
#menu > li {
    text-align: center !important;
    width: 85px !important;
}
newMenu.css (line 31)
#menu a, #menu a:visited, #menu a:hover, #menu li {
    color: White;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Here is an image to better describe what is happening:

[image: Navigation Menu]

What I need to happen is when someone clicks on the purple section to take them to the appropriate link.  Right now the blue rectangle is the only way to activate the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rA86g/1/)

to increase the click area of a link, add `padding` to the `a` element rather than giving width to the `li`.

instead of using width and height to determine the size of the links, let `padding` do it for you too, making the `li` stretch to fit. just make sure you set `a` to `display:block` so that it will expand.

if your links have a pre-determined width, it's best you set the width to the `a` element also (preferrably min-width so that the cell can expand to the text)

and to add to that, elements that have `float:left` are already `display:block`, so no need to define `display:block` if it has `float:left`

Comment: The individual who created the above menu must have some other things going on.  I can't see to get it to work with your suggestions.  It simply pushes home down and is barely visable.  I do see how it works in your demo however.  I might have to dig deeper to see what all is going on here.